# Resize aid needed in Html and Css

Tags: html, css, web

When I resize my brand new html and css page, it doesn't look exactly how I want it too. Below is the ideal look of my website.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFkPL.png)

However, when I go full screen, the website looks like this,

[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKRC9.png)

As you can see, the words on the page shift too much to the right, how could I fix this?

Here is my code.

```
<body>

<header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="logo"></h1>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <font color="white"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></font>
          <font color="white"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></font>
          <font color="white"><li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li></font>
          <font color="white"><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li></font>
       </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

    </body>






body {
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {

background-image: linear-gradient(darkblue, royalblue);
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 23px;

  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;


  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Note: I borrowed this code from an excellent video on how to make a nav bar.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEmysQARWFU

Comment: Please post the code itself in the question. Never post _images_ of code.

Comment: Please post the code as a Snippet. Never post images as the code

Comment: May I ask what is wrong with posting code as an image

Comment: People need to be able to run code to see what it does currently and to test possible solutions. And nobody wants to spend time duplicating code off an image when they could simply copy and paste it.

Comment: Okay, I have now pasted the code into the question

Comment: Please I need help urgently

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase the 'list' element 'margin-left' css as shown below. Also, you can remove the 'font' elements. They are invalid html5 and, in your case, redundant as you already assigned the white color in css.

```
nav li {

  margin-left: 100px;

  }
```

Comment: You are a life saver. I am forever grateful.